# Are there some Python implementations of the Schwarz Christoffel mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, conformal-geometry

I am interested in Python implementations of the Schwarz Christoffel mapping for simply and doubly connected polygonal domains. Well, I know that by now multiply connected domains can be dealt with, with the works of several authors (Tom DeLillo, Alan Elcrat, John Pfaltzgraff, and Darren Crowdy, to name a few). But to start with, I would like to know if someone has implemented some numerical algorithms in Python, similar (to some extent) to say the Schwarz-Christoffel Matlab toolbox, developed I think originally by Driscoll and Trefethen.

For instance, one big issue is to find the preimages of the polygonal vertices, the so-called parameters of the mapping. This is non-trivial. There are also various numerical issues with branch cuts. These are some numerical issues that one has to deal with. Of course, the Matlab toolbox solves all these issues, but since I only have access now to Python, I would like to know if these have been implemented in Python. If not, I may be interested in trying to implement them.

Edit: I was able to find some Python codes, to accomplish part of what I wanted, namely the programs linked to from http://planetmath.org/SchwarzChristoffelTransformationCircularVersion, in section 0.3. They seem to implement the mapping itself, when the "preimages" are also input. But they do not solve the issue of finding the actual preimages, that would produce a desired polygonal region. So this is good, but the tough part remains to be programmed, it seems.

Update: I have now implemented the Schwarz-Christoffel forward mapping in Python. However, while finding the preimages, some preimages tend to cluster really close together, so much that they are practically indistinguishable, numerically speaking. Anyone knows how to solve this clustering issue? I have only read so far Trefethen's original algorithm. By reading a little bit one of Driscoll's articles on the Matlab SC-toolbox, it seems that the algorithm using cross-ratios and Delaunay triangulations handles well the crowding problem. The only problem is, it would take me some time to implement it. Using the more basic algorithm by Trefethen, and using the usual Gauss quadrature (rather than the more suitable Gauss-Jacobi one) but with smaller and smaller intervals as one approaches the preimages, I was only able to get conformal maps into rectangles of aspect ratios less than 5 approximately (at least this is the case with the current version of my Python code).

Comment: I don't know the answer definitively. It's worth pointing out, though, that Driscoll and Trefethen are real experts in both Schwarz-Christoffel transformations and Matlab programming. That Matlab toolbox is meant to illustrate their research. I'd be very surprised if there's any Python code of similar quality. The vertex preimage problem, in particular, is pretty tricky because of the way those preimages tend to cluster close to one another. As much as I like playing with SciPy, I don't know that its polynomial solvers are up to the task.

Comment: Maybe we can try to translate the Matlab code into NumPy/SciPy?

Comment: @MarkMcClure, you are probably right, but the applications I have in mind (with my collaborators) have a small number of vertices, so I hope I can manage with Python.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I have now experienced what you were warning me about: the "clustering" of preimages issue. Do you think the problem can be circumvented within Python? The solver fsolve in scipy.optimize seems to only handle numpy.float. Any suggestions anyone please?

Comment: @Malkoun Two things come to mind: [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) and [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), which both have multi-precision polynomial rootfinders. My preference would be mpmath, if it works, because it's a simple library that you can import into your program like any other. Sage is a full featured system for mathematics that's built on top of its own, included Python. Sage can access [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) to solve this kind of polynomial. Again, though, I really don't know if either will work. I'd love to see the result, if they do, though!

Comment: @Mark McClure Thank you so much. I shall try mpmath first. I can send you a preprint once the project is done. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, so far, I was only able to get aspect ratios less than 5. I tried using mpmath, but at some point, it gets much slower than with usual numpy floats and complex numbers (interestingly the solvers do reasonably fast, but at the end, when I try to compute the S-C mappings for a somewhat big number of points, it takes a long time, and then it returns an error. There is probably something I need to fix in my own code though).

Comment: Related to this post, I have ported Driscoll's SC Toolbox library to Octave. SC Toolbox is a nice library written by Toby Driscoll for Matlab for numerically computing the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping. In case someone is interested in testing my port, here is the link: https://github.com/joemalk/sc_toolbox_octave